# What is the difference between "$var" and ${var}?

Tags: bash

When expanding a variable in `bash`, I usually use `${var}`, however I often also see `"$var".` The variables I am talking about are for passing arguments to bash functions in scripts. I do not need them or necessarily want them to use globbing or other fancy stuff. It is merely used for passing around strings. So which expansion is better for this case?

Comment: I'd say it's closely related. However, putting `"$varname"` out there is very different to `$varname`, which is talked about in the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are orthogonal to each other, and you need to understand both:

- [Word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)
- [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

This is a big subject in Bash, which can cause endless opportunities for subtle bugs, so any explanation here will not be complete. With that in mind:

- `${var}` as opposed to `$var` separates the variable `$var` from any surrounding code. For example:

  ```
  $ var=foo
  $ echo $variable
  ```

  This prints nothing (unless the variable `variable` is defined as well).

  ```
  $ echo ${var}iable
  fooiable
  ```
- "$var" ensures that no word splitting occurs on the contents of the variable:

  ```
  $ var='foo    bar'
  $ echo $var
  foo bar
  $ echo "$var"
  foo    bar
  ```

Again, this is just scratching the surface. If you want to write reliable Bash scripts, the linked articles (and pretty much all of that wiki) are excellent places to learn.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a matter of chosing one or the other, quotes are always recommendable while curly brackets are needed in some cases.

The quotes keep the format, while the curly brackets are used to perform [variable expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and some edge cases:

#### Importance of quoting

If we don't quote the variable call, the format is lost.

```
$ myvar="hello
how are you"
$ echo $myvar
hello how are you
$ echo "$myvar"
hello
how are you
```

Also, imagine you are storing a file name in a variable. If the file name happens to have a space, you cannot work with the file name properly unless you quote it.

```
$ echo "hello" > "my file"
$ ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me    0 Dec 20 10:41 my file

$ file="my file"
$ cat $file
cat: my: No such file or directory
cat: file: No such file or directory

$ cat "$file"
hello
```

#### Importance of curly brackets

If we don't use the curly brackets, we cannot use the variable and then a value without adding a space after the call of the variable.

```
$ myvar="hello"
$ echo ${myvar}1
hello1
$ echo $myvar1

$
```

Comment: I tried your example on my machine, and I get the same output for `$myvar`, `${myvar}` and `"$myvar"`. No differences there.

Comment: Sure? Try to write a file with two lines. Then do `myvar=$(cat file)` and try both ways, with and without quotes.

Comment: Yes, sure. `set` shows me this content for my variable: `HELLO=$'Hello\nHow are you?'`. All expansions give me the `\n` in my bash interactive shell. Maybe it's my settings...

Comment: OK, just added another example of the importance of quoting variables. In this case, for file names.

Answer (score 3):

${var} is better choice because you could see clearly the name of the variable.

For exemple :

```
var = "hello"
echo ${var}_1
hello_1
echo $var_1
```

Nothing appears for `echo $var_1` because bash thinks you try to access the variable `var_1`